# Creating fragment by external event == possible IllegalStateException?

Tags: android, fragment, illegalstateexception

Let's imagine I have an activity that registers BroadcastReceiver to listen for some event that independent to activity's lifecycle. Receiver can be registered on the activity's  onStart/onStop or onResume/onPause. When event received, I want to create and show a fragment, for example to show event details. This works, but sometimes app crashes with "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState".

I think, this may comes when activity going to pause and stop state, already saved its internal state, but BroadcastReceiver is not already unregistered, and at this moment comes new external event.

Fragment manager saves it's state on onSaveInstanceState(). According to official documentation, "If called, onSaveInstanceState() will occur before onStop(). There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause()". So, even I will registered receiver on the onResume() and unregistering on the onPause(), there is no guarantees to avoid IllegalStateException because activity can save it's internal state before onPause().

Maybe, the possible solution is override onSaveInstanceState() and set here the own boolean flag like mStateSaved. And, when new event received, analyze this flag: if it was set, assume that activity going to pause-stop state, and do not start fragment transaction.

I'm interesting, maybe there is the better solution.

Thank you for your attention!

**Updated** (code example, Fragment):

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mActionInformer.addObserver( onActionInformerUpdated );
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();        
    mActionInformer.deleteObserver( onActionInformerUpdated );
}    

Observer onActionInformerUpdated = new Observer() {
    @Override
    public void update( Observable observable, Object data ) {            
        TaskEvent event = (TaskEvent) data;
        if( event == TaskEvent.START ) {
            setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility( true );
        } else {
            setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility( false );
            // update ActionBar
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            // handle authorisation event
            if( event == TaskEvent.AUTH ) {
                String msg = mActionInformer.getExtraMessage();
                DialogFragment dlg = AuthorisationDialog.newInstance( msg );
                dlg.show( getFragmentManager(), "Authorisation" );
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you show some code, for example how do you start the fragment? Is your broadcast receiver active only when your app is open (Otherwise it'd be good to notify the user through status bar about new event)? Just trying to understand the context more.

Comment: My BroadcastReceiver registered programmatically, so it is active when activity is alive, betwwen onStart and onStop, or between onResume and onPause. Will prepare some code example today and update my question. Thanks for answer!

Comment: You should only let the activity/fragment update it self. It runs on its own thread. Another approach would be to relaunch the activity/fragment with some new info that you've received.

Comment: Why I can't update something in my activity/fragment by external event? This event comes to me as broadcast, this broadcast is in context of main app thread, so there is all ok. Relaunch activity or fragment is useless for me because of unwanted transition effects and time to relaunch a huge amount of code. I think, there is no problem to do someting by external event (broadcast) - but sometimes IllegalStateException causes. And I think this happens because FragmentManager saves its internal state earlier than I can unregister my BroadcastReceiver